# How to populate a nested field in mongoose in a NestJS app

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

In a NestJS application I have 3 .model.ts files,
the 2nd is nested in the first and the third is nested in the 2nd.
However I want to populate fields from the first into the 3rd by partnerId

the first one is `user.model.ts`

```
// user.model.ts
import { Schema, Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose'

import { Partners, PartnersSchema } from './partners.model'

@Schema({
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  timestamps: true,
})
export class User {
  @Prop()
  name: string

  @Prop()
  shortCode: string

  @Prop({ type: PartnersSchema })
  partners: Partners
}

const OrganizationSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Organization)
```

The 2nd one is `partners.model.ts`

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose'

import { PartnerHistoryEntry, PartnerHistoryEntrySchema } from './partner-history-entry.model'
import { PartnerRequest, PartnerRequestSchema } from './partner-request.model'

@Schema({
  _id: false,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
})
export class Partners {
  @Prop({ type: [PartnerRequestSchema], default: [] })
  requests: PartnerRequest[]

  @Prop({ type: [PartnerHistoryEntrySchema], default: [] })
  history: PartnerHistoryEntry[]
}

const PartnersSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Partners)

export { PartnersSchema }
```

And the 3rd one is `partner-request.model.ts`
In this PartnerRequest model, I am trying to populate the partnerName and partnerShortCode fields based on the partnerId (which refers to a User entity) in order to keep them up to date.

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-cycle
import { User } from './user.model'

@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
  _id: false,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
})
export class PartnerRequest {
  @Prop()
  partnerId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId

  @Prop()
  partnerShortCode: string

  @Prop()
  partnerName: string
}

const PartnerRequestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(PartnerRequest)

PartnerRequestSchema.virtual('partnerName', {
  ref: User.name,
  localField: 'partnerId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
})
PartnerRequestSchema.virtual('partnerShortCode', {
  ref: Organization.shortCode',
  localField: 'partnerId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
})

PartnerRequestSchema.pre(
  ['find', 'findOne', 'count', 'findOneAndDelete', 'findOneAndRemove', 'findOneAndUpdate'],
  // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
  function () {
    this.populate('partnerName')
    this.populate('partnerShortCode')
  }
)

export { PartnerRequestSchema }
```

My first issue is that I am getting an error due to the fact that I am importing `User` in `partner-request.model.ts` and importing `PartnerRequest` in `user.model.ts` `Dependency cycle via ./partners.model:4eslintimport/no-cycle`
that I am disabling with `eslint-disable-next-line import/no-cycle`

The second issue is that at the end of `partner-request.model.ts` in the ref. It doesn't complain for `ref: User.name` but it shows an error for `ref: User.shortCode`:

`Property 'shortCode' does not exist on type 'typeof User'.ts(2339)`

And then the main issue is that it doesn't work.
If I try the endpoint with Postman, `partnerName` and `partnerShortCode` are not being populated inside the requests

Example of a User and what I would like to achieve

```
{
  "name": "George",
  "shortCode": "GEO1",
  "partners": {
    requests: [
      {
        "partnerId": "6392d356b5cf1ad1ad75b887",
        "partnerName": "Ben", // is missing at the moment, should be populated
        "partnerShortCode": "BEN2" // is missing at the moment, should be populated
      },
    history: []
  }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?